# Inserting into MongoDB on top of stack and listening for updates

Tags: mongodb, node.js

Here is my case:
I have a MongoDB collection in Node.Js.

Let's say three elements: **a, b, c** I want to insert new element as the first one and want the last one to go out.

So it would be:
**d, a, b**

In next iteration:
**e, d, a**

1.How to do that kind of insetion?

2.Is there a chance to listen for those insetions from another node.js app? Something like

```
collection.on('update', function() {
  console.log('updated');    
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) in MongoDB preserve insertion order and discard the oldest items based on the total collection size (unfortunately measured in bytes). Seems like ideal fit for your scenario.
2. I believe there is no trigger/notification mechanism in MongoDB yet, only manual polling.

Comment: You can use the `max` parameter when creating a capped collection to specify the maximum number of objects that will stay in the collection: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-max

Comment: For anyone that comes across this now, they've added this functionality in Mongo 3.6 with Change Streams: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this would be to write a custom Queue object that would dequeue the last item when a new item was enqueued if the total number of items in the queue exceeded your requirements, and emit an 'item added' event that other parts of your application could listen for.

Here's some generic example code in which you would replace refs to Array, length, shift() and unshift() with calls to MongoDB:

```
var util=require('util'),                         // for inheritance
    EventEmitter=require('events').EventEmitter, // for event handling
    MaxQueueItems=10;                             // default total items in queue

var FixedSizeQueue=function(max){
  this._storage=[]; // replace with call to MongoDB
  this._max_items=max||MaxQueueItems;
};

util.inherits(FixedSizeQueue,EventEmitter); // now I can emit

FixedSizeQueue.prototype._add=function(item){ // private
  // replace with call to MongoDB
  this.emit('onItemAdd', this._storage.unshift(item), item);
};

FixedSizeQueue.prototype._remove=function(){ // private
  // replace with call to MongoDB
  var item=this._storage.shift();
  if(item) {
    this.emit('onItemRemove', this._storage.length, item);
    return item;
  }
};

FixedSizeQueue.prototype.enqueue=function(item){
  if (this._storage.length+1 > this._max_items) {
    this._remove(); 
  }
  this._add(item);
  return(this); // for chaining
};

FixedSizeQueue.prototype.dequeue=function(){
  return this._remove();
};
```

which could be used as:

```
var q=new FixedSizeQueue(3); // a queue with only three items

q.on('onItemAdd',function(len,item){
  console.log('item added, queue now contains '+len+' items.');
});

q.on('onItemRemove',function(len,item){
  console.log('item removed, queue now contains '+len+' items.');
});

q.enqueue(1); // emits onItemAdd, queue = (1)

q.enqueue(2); // emits onItemAdd, queue = (2,1)

q.enqueue(3); // emits onItemAdd, queue = (3,2,1)

q.enqueue(1); // emits onItemRemove and onItemAdd, queue = (4,3,2)
```

console output:

```
item added, queue now contains 1 items.
item added, queue now contains 2 items.
item added, queue now contains 3 items.
item removed, queue now contains 2 items.
item added, queue now contains 3 items.
```